# php security with Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Being a newbie I thought I understood what to do from a security standpoint but I still need some help.

I have a form that takes in a number of things about a camera's details.  Such as the camera name and a number of other options that are part of an html `select`. I process this in php:

```
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();

if (isset($_POST['addcamera'])) {

    //process changes to camera options 
    if ( !empty($_POST['camera_type']) && !empty($_POST['camera_status']) && !empty($_POST['camera_name']) && !empty($_POST['camera_quality']) && !empty($_POST['email_notice']) )
    {       
        $add_name = JRequest::getVar('camera_name', 'Default Camera', 'post', 'STRING');
        $add_quality = JRequest::getVar('camera_quality', '', 'post', 'STRING');
        $add_motion_detection = JRequest::getVar('camera_status', '', 'post', 'STRING');
        $add_email_notice = JRequest::getVar('email_notice', '', 'post', 'STRING');
        $camera_type = JRequest::getVar('camera_type', '', 'post', 'STRING');
        //and so on...

        //then I add to DB
        $query_insert_camera = "INSERT INTO #__cameras (camera_status, camera_name, camera_quality, email_notice, camera_type, camera_hash, camera_sensitivity, user_id) VALUES ('".$add_motion_detection."','".$add_name."','".$add_quality."','".$add_email_notice."','".$camera_type."','".$add_camera_hash."','".$add_sensitivity."','".$user->id."')";
        $db->setQuery($query_insert_camera);
        $db->query();
```

I do use jquery validation for my forms and on the php side of things since I'm using Joomla I'm using getVar: http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest::getVar. I believe I'm covering myself from XSS and SQL attacks but could someone confirm that this is the right approach?

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: injection:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection, manual:http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase - "Preparing the query" header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, as long as you keep your joomla core up to date, there are less risks.

These links might give you an idea not only about the XSS and SQL attacks in joomla for your extension:

- http://www.itoctopus.com/10-reasons-why-your-joomla-website-got-hacked
- http://docs.joomla.org/Category:Security_Checklist

You can use one of these plugins as well to reinforce your security against those attacks:

- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/site-protection

And here's the code of getVar where you can see how protected your site is against SQL injection and XSS:

- http://hg.joomla.org/joomla-platform/src/247ba8d88526/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php#cl-84

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you are wide open to SQL injection - or am I missing something.

What happens if someone passes in a camera name along the lines of

```
foo';EVIL_SQL_HERE;
```

as far as I can see you will execute there SQL it meets the criteria of STRING.

I think you need to use the $db->getEscaped() function around each of the variables generated from user input (assuming Joomla 1.6+) AND then $db->Quote() to wrap quotes around the variables to be stored in the database.

Here is a line from a fairly typical model:

```
$search = $db->Quote('%'.$db->getEscaped($search, true).'%');
```

Comment: I started using `$db->quote()` on Joomla 1.7.  I guess I should be using `$db->getEscaped()` instead?  According to the SQL section in this guide: http://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines it shows `$db->quote()` is all that is needed?  Although Joomla docs tend to be severely out of date.

Comment: I just came back to correct my post. You should be using variants of both. Escape the input, then quote it before/during storing. I've only just started coding for J2.5 so I'm not fully up to speed on the specifics - and there appear to be two variations of the database class (or two ways to use it) one backwards compatible with the older J1.5 way of doing things and a new object orientated way.

Comment: It looks like your double escaping with that code? Also technically this is its equivalent `$search = '\'%'.$db->getEscaped($search, true).'%\''`